# issue with handle multiple process at a time with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database in which I have more than 150 000 records.

and I want to make a page where I can get each and every record from database check that each record with one API and update status every day.

and I have a question that how can I make function takes 1000 records at a time after that 1000 record complete their execution and update that in database after that another 1000 queued in that process.

can anybody help me with this process

Comment: Process them in 1000 chunks?

Comment: @vivek_23 yes I want to set the process in short chunks

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: You can set cron job to run that code multiple times with limit 1000 and make a field cronstatus = 1 and check in your where condition when cronstatus != 1. And one more field cronrundate to check cronrundate = todaydate and cronstatus !=1

Comment: @Sachin can you please explain

Comment: Why do you want to do the this in chunks?

Comment: @MNJ -  I have posted answer to explain my comment. Please see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

1. set cron job which runs the code with limit 1000.
2. Make two fields in your table cronstatus = 0(default 0) and cronrundate (which store date)
3. Your where condition in query to get result would be - where cronstatus != 1 and cronrundate = '02/01/2020'. // use php date function
4. when your code run make cronstatus field  = 1 and set cronrundate = '02/01/2020'.(use php date function to set today date).
5. Repeat step 3 with limit 1000 until your all data have cronstatus = 1 and crondate = today.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **LIMIT** and **OFFSET** clauses in query for fetching 1000 record at once.

It is advisable to retrieve records always with specific limit.

More details can be gathered from this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

Comment: Note that in the absence of an ORDER BY clause, these terms are fairly meaningless

Comment: Yes, @Strawberry, I do agree with your kind suggestion, that it is a good practice to always use the **LIMIT** clause with the **ORDER BY** clause to constraint the output in the specific order.